# Group by when there is no "GroupID" column (EF Group by multiple columns, Page, Maintain Group Code)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2016

This isn't specifically about 1 thing but most trying to figure out a good solution knowing that I don't have the ability to change the C# code much. I currently have a Grid(DataTables.net) It is using MVC and EF. For everything else it works just fine but i have been given new probably I have a dataset in SQL where each row may or may not have a child row.
*(Also Note that this example uses, Linqkit for dynamic Where, and the Dynamic Linq NugetPackage for OrderBy)*

The user would like to see 10 things on returned. So there may be 10 records or 20 records returned but still a max of (10 groups). The current code that calls the DB looks like the following:

```
 var rslt = await _context.DrinksTable
        .AsExpandable()
        .Where(whereClause)
        .OrderBy(sortBy, sortDir)
        .Skip(skip)
        .Take(take)
        .ToListAsync();
```

The actually data looks like the following.  DrinksTable
[image: DrinksTable]

**The GroupId Doesn't really exist**; its just showing the Relationship in this illustration.

But The only way to know if a row has a child is to match on Drink Type, Available, use Shaker, Whisky, and Cola.
The Glass size determines if a record has a child or not and the Price/oz is just attribute data.

So here's the issue. how do I structure/query the record set in a way that the EF code will continue to work as is?  I'm stumped..  Started to create a few views but not sure if it will work.  I need the Paging to continue to operate as currently is.   If I submit to take 2 I need to get back the top 5 records.

**Not sure where to go with this, After a few passes it doesn't look like its actually working here's the updated code**

```
        var rslt = await _context.DrinksTable
        .AsExpandable()
        .Where(whereClause)
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.DrinkType, x.Available, x.UseShaker, x.Whiskey, x.Cola})
        .OrderBy("Key.DrinkType", sortDir)
        .Skip(skip)
        .Take(take)
        .SelectMany(x => x).ToListAsync();
```

**I couldn't get the SelectMany() to Maintian the Groups so I ended up going this route.  Its not complete yet, but its pretty close hope this helps. If someone knows a more efficient way to write this let me know. Thanks again.**

```
             int take = 2;
            string sortBy = "Key.Whisky";
            string sortDir = "Asc";
            int skip = 0;

            var xx = db.DrinksTable;

            var rslt = db.DrinksTable
                .GroupBy(x => new {x.Whisky, x.Available, x.Cola, x.DrinkType, x.UseShaker})
                .OrderBy(sortBy, sortDir)
                .Skip(skip)
                .Take(take)
                .ToList();
```

And to Maintain the Groupings with Unique values ended up Looping through and adding back in a Unique Identifier.

```
        List<DrinksTableDTO> dtDTO = new List<DrinksTableDTO>();
            //ToDo Create List with Parent and children. 
            int uniqueGroupCode = 1; 
            foreach (var itm in rslt)
            {
                // Parent Level here
                var topLevel = itm.Key;                  
                foreach (var snd in itm)
                {
                    //ToDo Create children and add to list 
                    dtDTO.Add(new DrinksTableDTO
                    {
                       GroupId = uniqueGroupCode,
                       Whisky =  snd.Whisky,
                       Available = snd.Available,
                       Cola = snd.Cola,
                       DrinkType = snd.DrinkType,
                       GlassSize = snd.GlassSize,
                       UseShaker  = snd.UseShaker,
                       Id = snd.Id
                    });
                }
                uniqueGroupCode++;
            };
```

***IF anyone has a cleaner faster way of doing any part of this, post it up.  I'm all for it but this solved my issue of Selecting by Groups, Paging and Maintaining Unique Group Ids.***

Comment: I updated the title with what appears to be the actual root problem. From the supplied data it looks like the only 'means' of determining a group is when the Glass Size run resets: 12..16, 12..16..64, 12, ie. (It is very unfortunate the database does not contain a proper key for groups: has there been information dropped or is that the base table?)

Comment: Actually a set would be Where  (Drink Type, Available, Use Shaker, Whisky and Cola are the Same)

Comment: If the KEY *really is* (Drink Type, Available, Shaker, Whisky, Cola) - then use that as the key (*and re-update the title*): then it's just a `GroupBy(..)`. However, that key seems 'suspect' for several reasons. YMMV

Comment: There is no Group Key. :(  Thats all there is and I can query by that but how do I select (2 Groups) and expect 5 rows, Then try paging with that going on. Thats the Issue is how do I select certain number of groups, then page.

Comment: If there *is* a key, first step is to group: `GroupBy(x => new { x.DrinkType, x.Available, .. })`. Note that GroupBy can return an anonymously-typed object (well, it can return a number of things, including the easy-to-use-here syntax). Then, `Take` (and `Skip`) *applied to the groupings* to get the right groups/number of groups, and `SelectMany` to get rows back out of groups.

Comment: So is this question really, *"How can I group data by more than one field?"*

Comment: How to  take/Skip  by Group By data